Magento 2 : Intergration with outlook365
I have problems with pairing magento 2 and outlook365. I've heard about AUTH2 from last year, probably magento still don't have it.
But, settings looks correct.
Disable Email Communications: NO
Transport: SMTP
Host: smtp.office365.com
Port (25):  587
Set Return-Path: NO
Username: email
Password: Password
Auth: LOGIN
SSL: TSL
What is wrong here? Email works fine without any problems... What I'm doing wrong?
